# The edited data in the express server saved successfully in Mongo DB but when sent back to the React client slice fails to be saved in data state

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

This is the express server api to save the edited data from React client to Mongo DB. The code snippet of server api is

```
app.put(
        '/car/update/:id',
        requireLogin,
        upload.array('imageFiles'),
        async (req, res) => {
            try {
                const { id } = req.params;
                const {
                    carMakerName,
                    modelName,
                    modelYear,
                    engine,
                    maxPrice,
                    minPrice,
                    mpg,
                    range,
                    options,
                } = req.body;

                // Upload photo to AWS and get the URL
                let s3ImageUrls = [];
                if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
                        const result = await createPhoto(req.files[i]);
                        if (result) {
                            s3ImageUrls.push(result.Location);
                        } else {
                            console.log(`Error uploading image ${i + 1}`);
                        }
                    }
                }
                const updatedCar = await Cars.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    id,
                    {
                        carMakerName,
                        modelName,
                        modelYear,
                        engine,
                        maxPrice,
                        minPrice,
                        mpg,
                        range,
                        $set: {
                            options: Array.isArray(options) ? options : [options],
                            s3ImageUrl: s3ImageUrls,
                        },
                    },
                    { new: true } // Return the updated document
                );

                if (!updatedCar) {
                    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Car not found' });
                }
                res.status(200).json(updatedCar);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating car data:', error);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
            }
        }
    );
```

After the edited data saved in the Mongo DB successfully, it is responded back to the React slice. The slice code snippet is

```
const carSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'vehicle',
    initialState: {
        data: [],
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
        successMessage: null,
        selectedCarData: null,
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        // some other reducers are here.....

        builder.addCase(editData.pending, (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(editData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            console.log(' action.payload from editData.fulfilled', action.payload);
            let editedData = action.payload;
            state.data = state.data.push(editedData);
        });
        builder.addCase(editData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = action.error.message; // Log the error message
        });

        
    },
});
export const carReducer = carSlice.reducer;
```

But the error broke out when the data is passed as prop to the other React component,  saying the data.map is not a function. Obviously the edited data is not pushed to state.data.

I figured that if I switch the `state.data = state.data.push(editedData);` to
`state.data = [{ ...state.data, ...action.payload }];` then the error is gone. But the snippet of `state.data = [{ ...state.data, ...action.payload }]` doesn't make sense. It just a fluke that is working. Any idea what is the cause of the issue?  Please help to figure out the problem.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The editData.fulfilled should be changed to update the data change.

```
builder.addCase(editData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.isLoading = false;
    const editedData = action.payload;
    state.data = state.data.map((car) =>
    car.id === editedData._id ? { ...car, ...editedData } : car
    );
 });
```